# prediction error when using BMA package: newdata is missing variables

Tags: r, model, bayesian, predict

I am tring to use `BMA` package to implement out of sample forecast.
Here is my code:

```
out.3m<-bic.glm(x3,y3vec,strict = FALSE,OR = 50,glm.family=binomial(link = "probit"))

yfitout3=predict(out.3m,newdata=tail(x,1)) #where x has one more observation than x3.
```

I got:

> Error in predict.bic.glm(out.3m, newdata = tail(x, 1)) :
>     newdata is missing variables

However, when I use

```
yfitout3=predict(out.3m,newdata=tail(x,2))
```

It works.

Could you please tell me where is wrong?